# How best to translate "hopefully"?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

This is a word I've always had trouble with. I can say "Je suis plein d'espoir" to say I am hopeful, but how can I idiomatically express that something will *hopefully* happen? Phrases like "avec un peu de chance" do not feel very idiomatic to me nor accurate in meaning.

Comment: peut etre is one possible translation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“*Avec un peu de chance*” is to me most idiomatic way to translate “hopefully”.

I never saw “*avec espoir*” used actually, and well even if it doesn't seems like it is, “*avec un peu de chance*” is often used, and perfectly accurate.

Comment: _Avec espoir_ voir l'exemple (un peu loufoque) au [_Cambridge_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/hope_1?q=hopefully).

Answer (score 4):

I think @servabat is right. Another way would be to reformulate the whole sentence.

- On peut espérer que...
- En espérant que...
- J'ai bon espoir de...
- Il y a fort à parier que...

Comment: On pourrait aussi ajouter « Dans l'espoir de... » selon le contexte.

Answer (score 4):

i'm french and i agree with "espérons que" (let's hope that...). - sorry i can't comment nor vote Papa Poule's answer up yet because i don't have enough reputation.

There is no word to translate "hopefully" literally and i think you should avoid to stick to find one, but construct the sentence differently (with "espérons que")

Comment: ...and beware that "Espérons que" is followed by subjunctive

Comment: Thanks for your kind mention and especially for the gentle warning about the subjunctive! I've left "ira" but added "aille" to my answer and a link that seems to say that there is not total agreement on the "Espérons que + subjunctive" issue. "Espérer + subjunctive" in negative forms and question forms was/is pretty clear to me, but I'm still not absolutely sure about it in its imperative form. Regardless, thanks again and +1.

Comment: oh right ! you can use subjunctive or future ! I would say that subjonctive is a bit more formal and works for both present or future event :
In your exemple "ira" clearly refers to a future event, while "aille" can refer to both present or near future.

Answer (score 2):

Probably less idiomatic than the first two good answers and their comments, but I often use the imperative/suggestive form “**Espérons que**” to express the notion of “hopefully”/(“Let’s hope that …"):

“Espérons que tout [ira/aille](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/677.html) bien”

(But if you’re all alone talking or thinking to yourself [and you don’t have a tapeworm], I suppose this plural notion might be out of place and/or taken as an example of the “royal we”).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes something as simple as:

j'espère que, on espère que

Answer (score 0):

You can complement the sentence (without "hopefully") with "croisons les doigts", or "espérons-le"/"Je l'espère", or "soyons optimiste". For instance, with

> Hopefully, this answer will get some votes:

- Soyons optimistes, cette réponse recevra quelques votes,
- Cette réponse recevra quelques votes, je l'espère,
- J'espère que cette réponse recevra quelques votes,
- Croisons les doigts, cette réponse recevra quelques votes.